# Nested Argument Scopes

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

I need help in understanding this nested argument scoping in TensorFlow :

```
def vgg_arg_scope(weight_decay=0.0005):
  """Defines the VGG arg scope.
  Args:
    weight_decay: The l2 regularization coefficient.
  Returns:
    An arg_scope.
  """
  with arg_scope(
          [layers.conv2d, layers_lib.fully_connected],
          activation_fn=nn_ops.relu,
          weights_regularizer=regularizers.l2_regularizer(weight_decay),
          biases_initializer=init_ops.zeros_initializer()):
    with arg_scope([layers.conv2d], padding='SAME') as arg_sc:
        return arg_sc
```

What I understant is that the outer level scoping applies to functions

```
[layers.conv2d, layers_lib.fully_connected].
```

What does the inner level scoping do?

Answer (score 0):

The inner arg_scope applies `padding='SAME'` to `layers.conv2d` but not to `layers_lib.fully_connected`, which probably doesn't have a `padding` argument.